# ionic 2 side-menu filter for an array on page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

im currently facing a problem with my Ionic app. I am trying to filter Ionic cards on a page from a side-menu defined from the (app.html).This is a school project for my internship program and i would really appreciate the help.
The page looks like this:  [That is my page with the array to be filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVK5b.png) and   [This is my side-menu filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4ao3.png)

My code so far for the array page is as follows,thanks in advance:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocationsPage } from "../locations/locations";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { ToastController } from "ionic-angular";
import { RestPage } from "../rest/rest";
/**
 * Generated class for the ContentPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-content',
  templateUrl: 'content.html',
})
export class ContentPage {
  modifiedData: any;
  originalData: any;


  constructor(private toast:ToastController,private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public menuCtrl: MenuController) {
        this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
        this.menuCtrl = menuCtrl;
    // this.menuCtrl.enable(true, 'myMenu');

//array for the display of cards

//properties defined about the cards include:

//name-name of the Restaurant

//image-image to be used for the card

//text-text for the card

//PushPage-for pushing a specific page

//Price - defines price of a restaurant

// Cusisine - defines a restaurants Cuisine

//PAGE: SAME AS PUSHPAGE


    this.originalData=[
      {name:'Fairmont Hotel',image:'assets/images/fairmont.jpg',text:'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.', PushPage: 'RestPage',Price: 'low', Cuisine:'Kenyan',Page: RestPage},
      {name:'MarymountHotel',image:'assets/images/fairmont.jpg',text:'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.', PushPage: 'RestPage',Price: 'Midrange',Cuisine:'Ethiopian', Page: RestPage}
    ];
    this.modifiedData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalData));
  }


//toast message to welcome a user to the app
  ionViewWillLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data =>{
      if(data.email && data.uid){
        this.toast.create({
          message:'welcome to Rest',
          duration: 3000 
        }).present();
      }
    })
  }

  //onclick event
 itemSelected (PushPage) {
  //alert(page);
  var page = this.originalData.filter(function(it) {
    return it.PushPage == PushPage
  })[0].Page
  //alert(page);
   this.navCtrl.push(page);
 }

//reset function
reset(){
  this.modifiedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalData));
}

//filtering function
filter(){
this.modifiedData=this.modifiedData.filter((rest)=>
{ return rest.Cuisine=='Kenyan'});
}

//toggel menu function
 toggleLeftMenu() {
   this.menuCtrl.toggle('left');
 }

  toggleRightMenu() {
  this.menuCtrl.toggle('right');
 }

 //function that pushes from FAB button to LocationsPage
Locations(){
  this.navCtrl.push(LocationsPage);
}
//function directing to the rest page that contains restaurant details
Rest(){
  this.navCtrl.push(RestPage);
}
}
```

Code for the side menu is as follows:

```
<ion-menu side="left"  [content]="content">
  <ion-header id="background">
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="">
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>


      <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)">
        Reservations
      </button>
      <button ion-item (click)="openPage(friendsPage)">
        Settings
      </button>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>


<!-- second sidemenu -->

<ion-menu side="right"  [content]="content">
    <ion-header id="background2">

  </ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
    <p>Im looking for:</p>
    <ion-label stacked>Cuisine:</ion-label>
   <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
    <ion-option value="K">Kenyan</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="E">Ethiopian</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="I">Indian</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Vibe:</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Vibe">
      <ion-option value="C">Chilled</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="F">Formal</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>price:</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Price">
      <ion-option value="L">Low</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="M">Midrange</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="H">HighPriced</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <!-- grid for placing the buttons -->
  <!-- first grid for the reset button -->
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
      <button ion-button color="secondary" outline (click)='reset()'>Reset</button>
      </ion-col>

      <!-- second column for the apply button -->
      <ion-col col-6>
        <button ion-button color="secondary"  outline (click)='filter(rest)' >Apply </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content ></ion-nav>
```

Comment: no there is no error,its just that i have been stuck for quite sometime on how to implement the filter system in the app. I cant seem to find a way to link the side-menu filter with the array .

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper object for your `filter` f.e. `{price: string, vibe: string}` where you keep track of the selected filters.

**src/models/filter.model.ts**

```
export class FilterWrapper {
   price: string = "NONE"; //default value
   vibe: string = "NONE";
   cuisine: string = "NONE";
}
```

**src/app/app.component.ts**

Now when the filter changes (in app.component.ts) make your function like:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FilterWrapper } from '../models/filter.model';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent{
    filterWrapper: FilterWrapper;
    constructor(events: Events) { 
       // creates a filterwrapper {price: "NONE", vibe:"NONE",cuisine:"NONE"}
       this.filterWrapper = new FilterWrapper();
    }

    saveFilters() {
      this.events.publish('filters:changed', this.filterWrapper);
     // where this.filterWrapper contains the selected filters (ngModel on select list f.e.)
    }
}
```

**src/app/app.component.html**

```
<!-- only 1 example provided -->

<ion-select [(ngModel)]="filterWrapper.cuisine">
    <ion-option value="K">Kenyan</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="E">Ethiopian</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="I">Indian</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Now listen for this change event in your array page:

**src/pages/content.component.ts**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FilterWrapper } from '../models/filter.model';

export class ContentPage {

    filterWrapper: FilterWrapper = new FilterWrapper();
    allItems = []; // your 'all' item list to display, normally filled. 

    constructor(events: Events) {
      events.subscribe('filters:changed', filter => {
          this.filterWrapper = filter;
      }
    }

    // returns true if the item matches the selected filters
    // yes could be more efficient but this is more comprehensive.
    matchesFilters(item: any) {
       let filter = this.filterWrapper;
       let result: boolean = false;

       // default true in case cuisine is "NONE"
       let cuisineResult = true;
       if(filter.cuisine != "NONE") {
          cuisineResult = filter.cuisine == item.cuisine;
       }

       let vibeResult = true;
       if(filter.vice != "NONE") {
         vibeResult = filter.vibe == item.vibe;
       }

      let priceResult = true;
      if(filter.price != "NONE") {
        priceResult = filters.price == item.price;
      }

      // true if all are or false if one of them is false
      result = (cuisineResult && vibeResult && priceResult);
      return result;
    }
}
```

In your *src/pages/content.component.html* page you will have something like:

`<ion-item *ngFor="let item of allItems">`

Now since you can't have 2 `*`'s on 1 item which is kind of annoying a workaround would be to make:

```
<!-- loop through the list and create an item for all of them -->
<div *ngFor="let item of allItems">
 <!-- dont show the item if it doesn't match the filters --> 
 <ion-item *ngIf="!matchesFilters(item)>
   <!-- dont put your *ngIf on the <ion-card> else the <ion-item> will still be created and that takes up space in your page -->
   <ion-card>
    ....
```

Comment: hi,thanks again for the time. Kind of a newbie to ionic so im kinda having some trouble following your logic,could you please explain it..im, for example lost on whether to define the filter wrapper on the app.html or on the app.components.ts and what would the final function to trigger the filter.

Comment: @DevHig Hi Dev, I updated my answer. The filterwrapper will act like an object which you can just create by `export class`. The final function to set the filters as current selection and show/hide items is `saveFilters()` in `app.component.ts`. Hope I you understand what I'm doing here, else I'm more than willing to elaborate.

Comment: @DevHig no problem. What array do you need to pass to the filter? And could you share your JSON of which you create your items? Because I just assumed that your item list had the same properties as your filter but that might not be the case. ( please edit your question and add it in, will become messy in comments )

Comment: @DevHig that would mean that no item passes the `matchesFilters` function, or that it causes errors on page load.